# How to find and replace string having numbers with another string having number

Tags: sed, xml

I have an xml tag like `<bestAddressLine4></bestAddressLine4>`. I want to convert that to `<bestAddressLine4 />`

I am using below command but it is not working.

```
sed -i 's/<bestAddressLine4><\/bestAddressLine4>/<bestAddressLine4\/>/g' file.txt
```

But it is not working.

Please suggest me the proper command.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! How is it not working? Applying your `sed` script to the sample text you show seems to give the expected result (except for the missing space before `/>`). Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Maybe it's a file encoding issue.  What's the result of `file file.txt`?

Comment: @gng Can you share expected input and output on question please ?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect @bxm is on the right track.

That `sed` command, provided your implementation supports that non-standard `-i` extension should work as expected on an input that is encoded as per the user's locale character encoding (see output of `locale charmap`).

As those characters are all from the portable charset, it should even work in any locale on your system as long as the rest of the line also contains only character from the portable charset.

One possibility though is that that file be encoded in UTF-16 with BOM, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32 / UCS-4... which are encodings that are not compatible with the POSIX API (and cannot be the charmap used by any locale) as they have many characters whose encoding contains byte 0.

To process those, you'd need either to use tools or languages that can decode text in that format, or convert it in an intermediary encoding supported by your system (typically UTF-8, which is the most common Unicode encoding found on Unix-like systems).

`file file.txt` should tell you what encoding it's written in.

If it's UTF-16 (the most likely), you can do:

```
< file.txt iconv -f UTF-16 |
  sed  's|<bestAddressLine4></bestAddressLine4>|<bestAddressLine4/>|g' |
  iconv -t UTF-16 > new-file.txt
```

Or you could use `perl` (whose `-i` some implementations of `sed` have borrowed):

```
perl -Mopen='encoding(UTF-16)' -i -pe '
  s{<bestAddressLine4></bestAddressLine4>}{<bestAddressLine4/>}g' file.txt
```